# How to prevent CNAME file from getting dropped during Jekyll build process

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, cname

I'm using Jekyll with Forestry.io and GitHub Pages. Everything seems to be working properly except for when the build process runs and the site is copied to the `gh-pages` branch. All of the static files (eg. robots.txt and sitemap.xml) get copied, but the `CNAME` file for my custom domain does not.

If I change the file name to all lowercase (`cname`) then it gets copied. But GitHub Pages doesn't recognize a `cname` file.

I don't think anything in the build portion of the Forestry.io settings would cause this issue.

```
build:
  preview_command: bundle exec jekyll build --drafts --unpublished --future -d _site
  publish_command: bundle exec jekyll build -d _site
  preview_env:
  - JEKYLL_ENV=staging
  publish_env:
  - JEKYLL_ENV=production
  preview_output_directory: _site
  output_directory: _site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you publishing your build to Github Pages? Github Pages can/should contain the (Jekyll) source, not the build. So to be extra clear: Github Pages should contain .md files and not (built) .html files. The CNAME file is designed to be used by Github Pages, so Github Pages is not the culprit. Forestry.io or your build process probably is. Forget about the build process and publish your changes directly to your github pages branch. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. I had a fundamental misunderstanding of GitHub Pages. I was working under the assumption that GitHub Pages needed to serve up the built site.

The problem is definitely in the build process. But now I don't need to even worry about resolving that. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Good to hear that you understand it now. You are welcome!